# Can you run Xen on FreeNAS?

Tags: xen, freenas

I've seen lots of posts about running FreeNAS in a virtual enviroment but none about using FreeNAS as a host, is this possible? Ideally I would like to buy a HBA card which supports ISCSI passthough to Vmware ESXI and run everything under that but I can't afford it. Obviously you can install Xen on BSD so in theory it should work on FreeNAS but I was wondering if anyone had any practical experience with it?

Thanks,

Joe